# Affordable clothes for special needs son

Tags: clothes

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. We have a special needs son who is ten, but intellectually more like a nine month old, and physically like a three year old. We keep him in zipper PJ's a lot because he had a hard time getting out of them and we prefer that he keeps good clothes, and more importantly diaper, on. He's pretty much grown out of 5T's which is as big as we can find. At least cheaply. We have found 6T's and bigger online for $30+ each. It's like when you tag something as "special needs" the price triples! Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Fortunately "footed onsies" as they're called in the USA are becoming popular even for adults now as a novelty item, so they come relatively cheap in all sizes. For example this one is $16.99 on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/SleepytimePjs-Infant-Fleece-Onesie-Footed/dp/B012Y36ULS

Comment: Carters carries them online in kids sizes (4-14).  I have seem them in the larger Carter's storefronts just in the late fall/early winter season as well.  They are still $30 full price, but carters has sales for 50% off pretty regularly, and you can sign up for email coupons.

Comment: @Meg and Stacey - Feel free to answer te question. I haven't checked with the other mods, but I think this one is ok.

Comment: Agree - questions about where *specifically* to shop would be off topic, questions about how to more generally find affordable clothes seem appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to find some hidden gem that I haven't seen. Carter's has a lot of size variety as well as various sellers on Amazon. We've decided to bite the bullet and get him clothes on sale wherever we can. Guess that's the (literal) price we pay for having children that can't take advantages of economies of scale.

Comment: As your son gets older, you may also want to look into Target's line of adaptive clothing-- Nice features and styles for various needs, and priced similarly to their regular kids clothes.

Comment: @Meg Where has this been hiding? Thanks for the info!